# Get JQuery accordion of overlap content below instead of pushing down

Tags: jquery, layout, accordion

Does anyone know how to get JQuery's accordion to overlap content below instead of pushing it down? I have a single menu-item accordion, with content that I want to display and hide accordingly. (I could probably use JQuery to hide and show a Div using animations instead of using this route, but I'm curious and have invested a lot of time looking for an answer so far).

Higher z-index for the accordion and absolute/fixed positions for the elements below don't work.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: please provide screenshot, difficult to imagine without it or without code.

Comment: Can you post some code or a http://jsfiddle.net ? This can help us understand better your problem and see http://whathaveyoutried.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing your accordeon into `div`, and set the following properties of that `div`:

```
div 
{
height:150px;
overflow:visible;
}
```

Have a look at [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_overflow).

Comment: Thanks John, this got me a lot closer than I've been in days. The visible overflow works if you have a fixed height. Had a that the top accordion keeps opening up behind the accordion below, even if the z-index is higher. I just set the z-index of the accordion higher and it's working perfectly now.